# Scala paint example: hub is deprecated use broadcast

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying the application in - [30 minutes to make realtime paint](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHEbm-WEbRw) -  youtube video. I have tried to follow it as closely as possible and after all that just as when I thought it was completed, I get deprecation warnings!

I am trying to learn scala & play. Tried Googling a bit with no help; I just do not know where to start looking in order solve the problem.

The relevant code snippet comes around Minute:26 in the video. A copy here as well:

```
val hubEnum = Enumerator.imperative[JsValue]()
val hub = Concurrent.hub[JsValue](hubEnum)
var counter = 0

def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
}

def stream = WebSocket.async[JsValue] { request =>
  var out = hub.getPatchCord()
  counter += 1
  var pid = counter
  var in = Iteratee.foreach[JsValue](_ match {
    case message: JsObject => {
      hubEnum push(message ++ JsObject(Seq("pid" -> JsNumber(pid))))
    }
  })
  Promise.pure((in, out))
}
```

The error:

```
[warn] /home/user/devpt/testpaint/app/controllers/Application.scala:12: class PushEnumerator in package iteratee is deprecated: use Concurrent.broadcast instead
[warn]   val hubEnum = Enumerator.imperative[JsValue]()
[warn]       ^
[warn] /home/user/devpt/testpaint/app/controllers/Application.scala:12: method imperative in object Enumerator is deprecated: use Concurrent.broadcast instead
[warn]   val hubEnum = Enumerator.imperative[JsValue]()
[warn]                            ^
[warn] /home/user/devpt/testpaint/app/controllers/Application.scala:13: trait Hub in object Concurrent is deprecated: use Concurrent.broadcast instead
[warn]   val hub = Concurrent.hub[JsValue](hubEnum)
[warn]       ^
[warn] /home/user/devpt/testpaint/app/controllers/Application.scala:13: method hub in object Concurrent is deprecated: use Concurrent.broadcast instead
[warn]   val hub = Concurrent.hub[JsValue](hubEnum)
[warn]                        ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Concurrent.broadcast](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent%24) is the new way to manage broadcasting. It returns an Enumerator and a Channel inside a Tuple2.

The **Channel** is where you can send messages, via the *push* method.

The **Enumerator** is the way the clients will get the messages sent to the Channel, which you can process via an *Iteratee*.

The new [Websocket-Chat sample app](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/websocket-chat) shows the usage, download it and you can replace the relevant bits of code by the new way of Broadcasting messages in Play.

Comment: The warning says already that. And there is no documentation on how to use it.

Comment: @AndriusBentkus if you read the answer, I posted a link to the websocket chat sample which shows a working code example on how to use it. That should be more than enough documentation.